# Cannot access domain on local network

Tags: domain-name-system, apache2, internal-dns

I've recently moved our website to a new external server, but I can't access the site via the domain internally. You can access it via the IP address, but not from the domain. I've checked the DNS records and it has a 'www', '@', and even a '*.example.com' record, and all the appropriate A records that I've seen mentioned in other posts. I'm not sure what else needs to be done, but it's still not working. I know it's not just propagation because that's what I thought initially, but those DNS records have been set for weeks now. I can't set up a hosts file for everyone internally because that's just ridiculous. There has to be a way to properly set this up.

The local network is also using the domain, so I know this is a common issue, but all of the proposed solutions don't seem to help since I've already done them.

Dig / DNS Lookups all seem fine, they point to the IP address.

Comment: Maybe _your_ DNS isn't working properly? What does a `dig` or `nslookup` or anything tell you?

Comment: Everything seems kosher it all points to the IP address. I should add that the local network is also on the domain.

Comment: Proxy? You can access the page by external IP?

Comment: Yes, I can access it externally and via the external IP address.

Comment: Your edit..."The local network is also using the domain", what do you mean?

Comment: For example, we have Active Directory set up, and it's using the domain.

Comment: Do you have split DNS? If so - maybe the external and internal view of the zone are not coherent with respect to this website? Additionally - is there any chance that there may be a NAT involved somewhere?

Comment: @Tomek Thank you! It looks like I have to look more into this Split DNS. I've never heard of it before. Do you happen to know of any good resources on it?

Comment: split dns or split-horizon dns are your search terms. But - if you didn't know it you couldn't possibly set it up, could you? If I were you I would check if IP addresses to which your site resolves are the same on the Internet at large and your local intranet. If they are the same DNS is unlikely the cause. If they differ - here comes split DNS.